# Can we access service data changed by parent component in child component

Tags: angular

routing:

```
children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: parentcomponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: "welcome",
            component: childcomponent
          }]
```

In parent component: I have router outlet to load the child components

```
<router-outlet> </router-outlet>
```

`this.service.current="0";`
I'm setting data in service from parent component and trying to access same from child but unable to see any properties of service in child

in child component,
unable to access service value changed by parent

Comment: Post relevant code

Comment: Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Comment: Use Observable to subscribe for changes, check this example https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/02/07/angular-7-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Answer (score 0):

I would use an actual "service" to share states and data between components. I have a brief guide that you can check out at https://matthewdavis.io/theme-service.

Here is an example:

the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ThemeService {

    /**
     * Variable to hold our setting.
     */
    public darkMode: boolean;

    /**
     * Enable/disable "dark mode" by flipping the bit.
     */
    public toggle(): void {

        this.darkMode = !this.darkMode;

    }

}
```

app component:

```
import { Component }    from '@angular/core';
import { ThemeService } from './theme.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.scss' ]
})
export class AppComponent {

    /**
     * Inject the theme service which will be called by our button (click).
     *
     * @param {ThemeService} themeService instance.
     */
    public constructor(public themeService: ThemeService) {

    }

}
```

using the service in a view:

```
<div class="wrapper" [class.dark-mode]="themeService.darkMode">

    <div class="text">

        Dark Mode Enabled? {{ themeService.darkMode ? 'YES' : 'NO' }}

    </div>

    <div class="button">

        Parent Component

        <button (click)="themeService.toggle()">Toggle!</button>

    </div>

    <app-child></app-child>

</div>
```

This guide also has an accompanying code repo at https://github.com/mateothegreat/ng-byexamples-theme-service.

Hope this helps!
If not, please post the rest of your code as mentioned before.
-Matthew